# What is KAFKA_LISTENER option?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I'm studying kafka.
To test producing messages, I wrote this `docker-compose` file.

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 19092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 29092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 39092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

`zookeeper`, `kafka` was started up successfully, so I tried to produce messages with `kafka-console-producer.sh`.

```sh
> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --topic peter-topic
```

But I got this error.

```
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,610] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:19092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,610] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:19092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,713] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -3 (localhost/127.0.0.1:39092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,713] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:39092 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,814] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -3 (localhost/127.0.0.1:39092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-05-06 02:40:41,815] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:39092 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
...
```

Why they try to access localhost:19092,29092,39092?
I set `port forwarding` from 19092(+29092,39092) to 9092.

What thing I was wrong?
For what I should set up this option?